# How to initialise a contract with storage (contract unit)

Tags: contract

How do I initialise a contract with the following storage -

```
storage (contract unit);
```

Used after the command line parameter --init for contract deployment.

I have tried various formats but none of them are working.

This is running on the Alphanet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need quotes for the parameter itself, and inside quotes for the contract literal. It should look like this.

```
--init '"KT1..."'
```

Comment: I did try that but the following error comes up - Ill typed data: 1: "KT1PwX3RWLGikTRsDTmRh3Bnxs9dUphMn8GS" is not an expression of type contract unit
   Type string is not compatible with type unit.

Comment: You suggestion does work for - storage (contract string);

Comment: I updated my question to mention that this is running on the Alphanet.

Comment: https://alphanet.tzscan.io/KT1PwX3RWLGikTRsDTmRh3Bnxs9dUphMn8GS?default=origination

This contract takes a `string` parameter. It's thus a `contract string` and not `contract unit`

Comment: Ahh, ok, I understand now. The types after the contract are the expected parameters. I deployed a new contract with a Unit parameter (https://alphanet.tzscan.io/KT1UHQMbgKPjPVRVHaz78kRPPfTesEtRTPjv) and now my test contract is able to run correctly using this new deployed contract.  Thanks for your help.